# What is the difference between a state action and an entry action and what is the Papyrus counterpart of a state action

Tags: spring-boot, spring-statemachine, papyrus

I am playing around with the Spring state machine project and Eclipse Papyrus respectively.

I have two questions about actions:

1. What is the difference between a so-called `state action` and an `entry action` of a `State`?
2. What is the counterpart of a `state action` in Papyrus? The documentation describes only `entry` and `exit` actions.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Can't tell about Papyrus, but you can specify tree different actions for state. You can use following methods to avoid confusion:

- `stateEntry` - executed when entering the state.
- `stateDo` - also referred as state's action. Executed when entered the state, technically is executed after entry action.
- `stateExit` - executed prior to leaving the sate.

The long story short, `state action` is executed before `entry action`. If you need only one action for the state you can choose either.